# Fetching the records from DB2 and inserting into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, db2

We have an Cobol application which is using a DB2 database. I need to develop an application which will fetch the records from that DB2 database and insert the same into a SQL Server database. This should be happen in real time. My application needs to update the SQL Server database once the record is inserted into DB2. Max 30 min delay is acceptable. This involves huge volume of data and number of tables.

Which is optimistic way for achieving this, without affecting the performance?

Comment: Is this DB2 for i or DB2 for z/OS?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract data from DB via:

- Table federation (insert/select) or its equivalent en SQL Server.
- Export command
- ETL program or equivalent
- Performance unload, a add-in to DB2 that works directly with the containers and tablespaces, not with the database system

Each one is different, with different performance and price.